# Stubs, Fragments or Compound Controls?

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm new to Android and a confused about the options to group Views together.

Let's say I want to create a UI where I have 2 sections of controls (one with Buttons and one with text + Spinners) that are above each other in portrait mode and next to each other in landscape mode, and the same goes for the stuff within those sections. Obviously I would like to dynamically change this when the user changes from one mode to another.

So, do I use Fragments within Fragments or use them only the outer section and then a Compound Control for the inner elements? Or are Fragments even necessary and I should better stick to something else? What is the best practice here?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you show some screenshot or wireframe of the layout that you want to create ?

Answer (score 1):

In your example you would create two layout files. One that contained your buttons and the other that contained your spinners.

You would create a 3rd layout file for the portrait orientation and use the `include` tag to include your other layouts within the 3rd layout. Similarly for your landscape layout, you would include your inner UI layouts in that.

You could then use an Activity or a Fragment which would use only the main layouts and assuming they were placed into the correct layout folders, the fragment/activity would load the correct one based on your orientation.

Fragments within Fragments should be avoided unless you have a specific need for it. It works but in practice managing the lifecycle becomes tiresome.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
What do you mean by: "You could then use an Activity or a Fragment which would use only the main layouts and assuming they were placed into the correct layout folders, the fragment/activity would load the correct one based on your orientation." ?
How does an Activity know which one to load in portrait, etc.?

Comment: Explained in the documentation. See this link. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources